# ASP.net MVC 3 NAVIGATION ACCORDION Image path

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc

How to set path in css  for images in a different folder for ASP.net mvc 3.Because my ACCORDION is not sliding its in expanded mode.

Here is my code

```
.dcjq-icon {
height:17px;
width:17px;
display:inline-block;
background:#036 url(../images/nav-expand.png) no-repeat top;
border-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
position:absolute;
right:11px;
top:11px;
}
```

[image: File Structure]

[image: Template File]

[image: Error Page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
background:#036 url('/Content/images/nav-expand.png') no-repeat top;
```

Comment: I have changed but it is not displaying.I have added the images of both original and file which i am editing.

Answer (score 2):

in CSS, you have to rely upon relative path. Every thing is manipulated based on location of CSS file. Lets get to the concept first.

so when you do this `background-image:url('/Content/Images/...')`, the path that gets constructed is something like `http://domain/Content/Images`, so clearly it will ignore any virtual directory(if that is your case).

when you do this `background-image:url('../Images/...')`, it means, look for the path, just one above from the current location and current location is the location of your css file
so `../` means go one above the current directory.

Hence combining all these, you should do:

```
 background-image:url('../../Images/restofthePath')
```

or

```
//be aware that it will ignore any virtual directory
background:#036 url('/Content/Images/...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new folder `newfolder` and paste all required images to that folder

Css

```
background:#036 url(../newfolder/nav-expand.png) no-repeat top;
```

***Correct Answer is
background:#036 url('/Content/images/nav-expand.png') no-repeat top;***

Comment: i have checked that....person who has given you the answer is working in my corporate only...